# Set reminders for subscribed calendar individually

Tags: google-calendar

When you subscribe to a calendar in Google Calendar you can globally set default reminders for the particular feed in settings. But I find that I can't change those reminder settings for individual events in the feed. I keep getting "failed to save changes" (or something like that).

Is this just not possible in Google Calendar?

Comment: It doesn't look like you can change the reminder for individual events.

Comment: I didn't know you could set a global reminder for a calendar. This question itself solved my issue :)
However, it's quite awkward to be presented with the individual notification setting for an event but receiving that error. I got that as well o.O

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could copy an individual event to one of your calendars and set the event reminder on that. If it clutters your calendar too much, you might create a special calendar ("Reminders") just for that that you don't display with your other calendars.

Comment: Thanks.  I've used your suggestion.  A bit cumbersome, but it works.